# compare input value with database value using spring mvc

Tags: java, sql, spring-mvc

how to compare input value item_code1,item_code2 and so on with another table column item_code and then also compare stock with Quantity_reqd1,Quantity_reqd2() and so on  based upon item_code. If compare is true then generate report1 of that item otherwise generate report2.

```
@Controller
```

@RequestMapping("requirement")
public class RequirementController {

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RequirementEntity.class);

@Autowired
private RequirementService reqService;

@Autowired
private Master_service master_service;

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Autowired
private Stock_issuance_service stock_service1;

@Autowired
private Purchase_Order_Service purchase_service1;

@RequestMapping(value = "/sheet", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getRequirementJsp() {
    System.out.println("Controller is starting..");
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("requirement_sheet");
    mav.addObject("item", new Item_entity());
    mav.addObject("itemList", this.master_service.getItemList());
    mav.addObject("department", new department_entity());
    mav.addObject("departmentList", this.master_service.getDepartmentList());
    stock_register_dto dto = new stock_register_dto();
    mav.addObject("stock_register", dto);
    return mav;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/sheet", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveRequirement(@ModelAttribute("requirement") RequirementEntity req, RedirectAttributes rd,
        stock_register_dto dto, Purchase_Order_Entity order, ModelAndView modelAndView, ModelAndView modelAndView1,
        Stock_issuance_toDepartment stockIssuance, Session session, Integer item_code, Integer stock) {
    System.out.println("MAV is starting..");
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("requirement_sheet");
    mav.addObject("item", new Item_entity());
    mav.addObject("itemList", this.master_service.getItemList());
    mav.addObject("department", new department_entity());
    mav.addObject("departmentList", this.master_service.getDepartmentList());
    System.out.println("service is not starting..");
    this.reqService.saveRequirement(req);
    rd.addFlashAttribute("msg", "Requirement details added Successfully.");

    List<stock_register_dto> dataList = master_service.getStockRegisterList(dto);
    Map<String, Object> parameterMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    String hql = "FROM Stock_issuance_toDepartment where serial_no = (SELECT max(serial_no) FROM Stock_issuance_toDepartment) ORDER BY serial_no DESC";
    Session session1 = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Query query = session1.createQuery(hql);
    List list1 = query.list();
    try {
        String query1 = "SELECT item_code, stock FROM stock_requirement_register WHERE item_code=?, and stock=? ";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/bjspring", "postgres",
                "postgres");
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query1);
        ps.setInt(1, item_code);
        ps.setInt(2, stock);
        ResultSet out = ps.executeQuery();
        while (out.next()) {
            Integer code = out.getInt("item_code");
            Integer check = out.getInt("stock");
            if (req.getItem_code1().equals(code) && req.getQuantity_reqd1().equals(check)) {
                JRDataSource JRdataSource1 = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list1);
                parameterMap.put("datasource", JRdataSource1);
                modelAndView = new ModelAndView("report3", parameterMap);
                return modelAndView;
            } else {
                return new ModelAndView("redirect:requirement/genReport");
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mav;
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/genReport")
public ModelAndView generateReport(stock_register_dto dto, RequirementEntity req, Purchase_Order_Entity order,
        Stock_issuance_toDepartment stock, ModelAndView modelAndView) {
    Map<String, Object> parameterMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    /*
     * List<Stock_issuance_toDepartment> list1 = stock_service1.list(stock);
     * List<Purchase_Order_Entity> list2 = purchase_service1.list(order);
     */
    /*String hql = "FROM Stock_issuance_toDepartment where serial_no = (SELECT max(serial_no) FROM Stock_issuance_toDepartment) ORDER BY serial_no DESC";
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
    List list1 = query.list();*/

    String hql1 = "FROM Purchase_Order_Entity where serial_no = (SELECT max(serial_no) FROM Purchase_Order_Entity) ORDER BY serial_no DESC";
    Session session1 = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Query query1 = session1.createQuery(hql1);
    List list2 = query1.list();
    if (list2 != null) {
        JRDataSource JRdataSource2 = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list2);
        parameterMap.put("datasource", JRdataSource2);
        modelAndView = new ModelAndView("report2", parameterMap);
        return modelAndView;
    }
    return modelAndView;
}
```

}

entities:

```
public class RequirementEntity {

@Id
@Column(name = "serial_no")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer serial_no;

@Column(name = "stock_requirement_slip_no")
private String stock_requirement_slip_no;

@Column(name = "stock_requirement_slip_date")
private Date stock_requirement_slip_date;

@Column(name = "department_code")
private String department_code;

@Column(name = "item_code1")
private Integer item_code1;

@Column(name = "quantity_reqd1")
private Integer quantity_reqd1;

@Column(name = "item_code2")
private Integer item_code2;

@Column(name = "quantity_reqd2")
private Integer quantity_reqd2;

@Column(name = "item_code3")
private Integer item_code3;

@Column(name = "quantity_reqd3")
private Integer quantity_reqd3;

@Column(name = "item_code4")
private Integer item_code4;

@Column(name = "quantity_reqd4")
private Integer quantity_reqd4;

@Column(name = "item_code5")
private Integer item_code5;

@Column(name = "quantity_reqd5")
private Integer quantity_reqd5;

@Column(name = "work_order_no")
private String work_order_no;

@Column(name = "buyer")
private String buyer;

@Column(name = "item_name1")
private String item_name1;

@Column(name = "item_name2")
private String item_name2;

@Column(name = "item_name3")
private String item_name3;

@Column(name = "item_name4")
private String item_name4;

@Column(name = "item_name5")
private String item_name5;

public Integer getSerial_no() {
    return serial_no;
}

public void setSerial_no(Integer serial_no) {
    this.serial_no = serial_no;
}

public String getStock_requirement_slip_no() {
    return stock_requirement_slip_no;
}

public void setStock_requirement_slip_no(String stock_requirement_slip_no) {
    this.stock_requirement_slip_no = stock_requirement_slip_no;
}

public Date getStock_requirement_slip_date() {
    return stock_requirement_slip_date;
}

public void setStock_requirement_slip_date(Date stock_requirement_slip_date) {
    this.stock_requirement_slip_date = stock_requirement_slip_date;
}

public Integer getItem_code1() {
    return item_code1;
}

public void setItem_code1(Integer item_code1) {
    this.item_code1 = item_code1;
}

public Integer getQuantity_reqd1() {
    return quantity_reqd1;
}

public void setQuantity_reqd1(Integer quantity_reqd1) {
    this.quantity_reqd1 = quantity_reqd1;
}

public Integer getItem_code2() {
    return item_code2;
}

public void setItem_code2(Integer item_code2) {
    this.item_code2 = item_code2;
}

public Integer getQuantity_reqd2() {
    return quantity_reqd2;
}

public void setQuantity_reqd2(Integer quantity_reqd2) {
    this.quantity_reqd2 = quantity_reqd2;
}

public Integer getItem_code3() {
    return item_code3;
}

public void setItem_code3(Integer item_code3) {
    this.item_code3 = item_code3;
}

public Integer getQuantity_reqd3() {
    return quantity_reqd3;
}

public void setQuantity_reqd3(Integer quantity_reqd3) {
    this.quantity_reqd3 = quantity_reqd3;
}

public Integer getItem_code4() {
    return item_code4;
}

public void setItem_code4(Integer item_code4) {
    this.item_code4 = item_code4;
}

public Integer getQuantity_reqd4() {
    return quantity_reqd4;
}

public void setQuantity_reqd4(Integer quantity_reqd4) {
    this.quantity_reqd4 = quantity_reqd4;
}

public Integer getItem_code5() {
    return item_code5;
}

public void setItem_code5(Integer item_code5) {
    this.item_code5 = item_code5;
}

public Integer getQuantity_reqd5() {
    return quantity_reqd5;
}

public void setQuantity_reqd5(Integer quantity_reqd5) {
    this.quantity_reqd5 = quantity_reqd5;
}

public String getWork_order_no() {
    return work_order_no;
}

public void setWork_order_no(String work_order_no) {
    this.work_order_no = work_order_no;
}

public String getBuyer() {
    return buyer;
}

public void setBuyer(String buyer) {
    this.buyer = buyer;
}

public String getItem_name1() {
    return item_name1;
}

public void setItem_name1(String item_name1) {
    this.item_name1 = item_name1;
}

public String getItem_name2() {
    return item_name2;
}

public void setItem_name2(String item_name2) {
    this.item_name2 = item_name2;
}

public String getItem_name3() {
    return item_name3;
}

public void setItem_name3(String item_name3) {
    this.item_name3 = item_name3;
}

public String getItem_name4() {
    return item_name4;
}

public void setItem_name4(String item_name4) {
    this.item_name4 = item_name4;
}

public String getItem_name5() {
    return item_name5;
}

public void setItem_name5(String item_name5) {
    this.item_name5 = item_name5;
}

public String getDepartment_code() {
    return department_code;
}

public void setDepartment_code(String department_code) {
    this.department_code = department_code;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "RequirementEntity [serial_no=" + serial_no + ", stock_requirement_slip_no=" + stock_requirement_slip_no
            + ", stock_requirement_slip_date=" + stock_requirement_slip_date + ", department_code="
            + department_code + ", item_code1=" + item_code1 + ", quantity_reqd1=" + quantity_reqd1
            + ", item_code2=" + item_code2 + ", quantity_reqd2=" + quantity_reqd2 + ", item_code3=" + item_code3
            + ", quantity_reqd3=" + quantity_reqd3 + ", item_code4=" + item_code4 + ", quantity_reqd4="
            + quantity_reqd4 + ", item_code5=" + item_code5 + ", quantity_reqd5=" + quantity_reqd5
            + ", work_order_no=" + work_order_no + ", buyer=" + buyer + ", item_name1=" + item_name1
            + ", item_name2=" + item_name2 + ", item_name3=" + item_name3 + ", item_name4=" + item_name4
            + ", item_name5=" + item_name5 + "]";
}
```

}

and second entity:

```
public class stock_register_dto  {

@Id
@Column(name = "serial_no")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer serial_no;

@Column(name = "date")
private Date date;

@Column(name = "sisr_no")
private String sisr_no;

@Column(name = "invoice_no")
private String invoice_no;

@Column(name = "vendor_code")
private String vendor_code;

@Column(name = "department_code")
private String department_code;

@Column(name = "item_code")
private Integer item_code;

@Column(name = "hsn_code")
private Integer hsn_code;

@Column(name = "purchase_price")
private Integer purchase_price;

@Column(name = "quantity_recd")
private Integer quantity_recd;

@Column(name = "quantity_issued")
private Integer quantity_issued;

@Column(name = "stock")
private Integer stock;

public Integer getSerial_no() {
    return serial_no;
}

public void setSerial_no(Integer serial_no) {
    this.serial_no = serial_no;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getSisr_no() {
    return sisr_no;
}

public void setSisr_no(String sisr_no) {
    this.sisr_no = sisr_no;
}

public String getInvoice_no() {
    return invoice_no;
}

public void setInvoice_no(String invoice_no) {
    this.invoice_no = invoice_no;
}

public String getVendor_code() {
    return vendor_code;
}

public void setVendor_code(String vendor_code) {
    this.vendor_code = vendor_code;
}

public String getDepartment_code() {
    return department_code;
}

public void setDepartment_code(String department_code) {
    this.department_code = department_code;
}

public Integer getItem_code() {
    return item_code;
}

public void setItem_code(Integer item_code) {
    this.item_code = item_code;
}

public Integer getHsn_code() {
    return hsn_code;
}

public void setHsn_code(Integer hsn_code) {
    this.hsn_code = hsn_code;
}

public Integer getPurchase_price() {
    return purchase_price;
}

public void setPurchase_price(Integer purchase_price) {
    this.purchase_price = purchase_price;
}

public Integer getQuantity_recd() {
    return quantity_recd;
}

public void setQuantity_recd(Integer quantity_recd) {
    this.quantity_recd = quantity_recd;
}

public Integer getQuantity_issued() {
    return quantity_issued;
}

public void setQuantity_issued(Integer quantity_issued) {
    this.quantity_issued = quantity_issued;
}

public Integer getStock() {
    return stock;
}

public void setStock(Integer stock) {
    this.stock = stock;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "stock_register_dto [serial_no=" + serial_no + ", date=" + date + ", sisr_no=" + sisr_no
            + ", invoice_no=" + invoice_no + ", vendor_code=" + vendor_code + ", department_code=" + department_code
            + ", item_code=" + item_code + ", hsn_code=" + hsn_code + ", purchase_price=" + purchase_price
            + ", quantity_recd=" + quantity_recd + ", quantity_issued=" + quantity_issued + ", stock=" + stock
            + "]";
}
```

Please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood you question and given code correctly, then below is the solution:

I just need an explanation for this below query you have written in saveRequirement() controller method:

```
SELECT item_code, stock FROM stock_requirement_register WHERE item_code=?, and 
stock=?
```

If the above query is just to check if there exist an entry with such item_code and stock then its fine but you could have applied count query rather then getting the result set and iterating on it. It can be costly in comparison with working on local variables itself.

The Solution:

Assuming that you are getting data in your entity class stored properly from the form in the saveRequirement() method

You can write a method in your RequirementEntity class which returns a Map collection (something like below)

```
public Map<Integer, Integer> getItemCodeList(){
    Map<Integer> response = new LinkedHashMap<Integer>();
    response.put(this.item_code1,this.quantity_reqd1);
    response.put(this.item_code2,this.quantity_reqd2);
    response.put(this.item_code3,this.quantity_reqd3);
    response.put(this.item_code4,this.quantity_reqd4);
    response.put(this.item_code5,this.quantity_reqd5);
    return response;
```

}

So when you have saved the form data in your RequirmentEntity class you can call this method to get a Map collection object and iterate over the keyset of this map using to compare each item_code received from form with the data in database.

```
//The place where you have called this below method
@RequestMapping(value = "/sheet", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveRequirement

//You can get data in a Integer List as below
boolean report = true;
Map<Integer,Integer> itemCodeList = req.getItemCodeList();
Set<Integer> keys = itemCodeList.keySet()
for(Integer key : keys ){
    if(!(report = compare(itemCodeList, item)))
        break;
}

if(report)
    //code for generate report here... or redirection code as per your logic
```

This above method compare() can be anywhere in your service class and you can call it here accordingly. You can write the code to compare the items in there. You can write query which matches the item code and quantity required at the same time, and call the generate report method from there itself.

But it seems (Correct me if I am wrong) from your code that you want to generate report for each item, and you are returning MV for each items matching the criteria which is not possible. You can segregate the list of items which are to be considered for report 1 and list of items to be considered for report 2. And move ahead accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for reply ...but how to compare item_code1, item_code2  and so on with item_code saved in different table stock_register and quantity_reqd1, quantity_reqd2 and so on with stock saved in stock register table and also check quantity based on item_code.

Comment: Hi as explained in the above code portion already! You can write that part of code in the compare method which is called inside the "for" loop which is iterating over the KeySet of items map. You can write our bussiness logic there like 

`public boolean compare(long itemCode, long quantity){

//check the item passed in this function with that in the database
//depending on the condition above you can proceed with checking the //quantity with your stock or exiting the code by returning false straight away.

}`